# How do I fix Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java?

Tags: java, macos, shell

I looked at every stackoverflow question related to the error:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java
```

Still not able to fix it.

I've been using Java 8 but I have to now use Java 6 for a different project. I feel like some settings from Java 8 is creating this issue.

My current .bash_profile is:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
# export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
# echo export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
# echo export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Trying to execute:

```
/develop/tools/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse -P ut -f /develop/projects/mynavi.wedding/source/pom.xml
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check permissions, maybe you have to `chmod +x` the executable file.

Comment: Are you using Linux or MacOS?

Comment: Im using a mac. @CoderinoJavarino chmod /develop/tools/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse -P ut -f /develop/projects/mynavi.wedding/source/pom.xml ?

Comment: Try running `/usr/libexec/java_home` on the command line. What does it print?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I get /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home so its probably pointing to the wrong path but don`t know how to fix that. I`ve made sure that Java 6 exists in the Java_Home path.

Comment: Since you want to use Java 6 instead of 8, why don't you just put `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/Java/6/installation` in your .bash_profile?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I made that change but still not working. I still get /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home when I type in /usr/libexec/java_home.

Comment: Yeah but I'm saying forget about /usr/libexec/java_home - you don't need that when using Java 6. Just do the assignment as in my previous comment . The command /usr/libexec/java_home prints the location of the *latest* Java installation, which is *not* what you want.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Ive tried..............export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)
# export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_152`
# export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
# /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
# export JAVA_HOME="`/usr/libexec/java_home`"
# export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
# export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)
```

Then test with:

```
java -version
```

Assuming you have Java 1.6 installed, and your path set up you should get something like:

> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)

Comment: I get Java version: 1.8.0_152, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre

Comment: Ok.  Maybe I should start from the beginning.  What do you get when you execute the command `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6` in Terminal?

Comment: Thanks!! I get /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: OK, that's good.   What do you get from the command `echo $PATH`?

Comment: I get /usr/local:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/blazesmith/visitors

Comment: That's probably OK for now, but you might want to investigate removing the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin` part if you want to switch between Java versions frequently.  What do you get from the command `which java`?

Comment: I get /usr/bin/java. Im going to be using Eclipse for a project in Java 6 and another project using Java 8, IntelliJ

Comment: OK, but Eclipse has a different way of configuring the compiler.  What do you get if you run `java -version` now?

Comment: I get java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)

Comment: Trying to execute /develop/tools/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse -P ut -f /develop/projects/mynavi.wedding/source/pom.xml but I keep on getting Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java

Comment: It seems that *somewhere* you have defined `JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home` instead of `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`.

Answer (score 0):

The following has been tested on my mac:

```
export JAVA_HOME="`/usr/libexec/java_home`"
```

Comment: try executing `/usr/libexec/java_home` on the command line and check the output. You should assign the output to the JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: Still not working...I get /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: You should first locate the Java 6 runtime on your mac (libexec is showing you the java 8 home). Once that is located, set the `Contents/Home` folder of the runtime as JAVA_HOME.

Comment: You are saying to do export JAVA_HOME=$(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home) in my .bash_profile correct? Tried that and I get -bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home: is a directory